# Rails 4 migration to change columns data type from string to integer and back preserving data (postgres)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, rails-migrations

I need to convert `string` fields into `integer` and use `enum` instead.
What is the best way to do this without losing data?

This is current migration:

```
class CreateSystems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :systems do |t|
      t.string :operation
      t.string :status

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Then I change type of the fields like so:

```
class ChangeColumnsForSystems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :systems, :operation, :integer
    change_column :systems, :status, :integer
  end
end
```

And update model file.

/app/models/system.rb

```
...
enum operation { start: 0, stop: 1 }
enum status { init: 0, working: 1, complete: 2 }
...
```

How can I update old data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some research I found this to be a proper solution.

```
class ChangeColumnsForSystems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :systems, :operation, "integer USING (CASE operation WHEN 'start' THEN '0'::integer ELSE '1'::integer END)", null: false
    change_column :systems, :status, "integer USING (CASE status WHEN 'init' THEN '0'::integer WHEN 'working' THEN '1'::integer ELSE '2'::integer END)", null: false
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:**
In some cases you will have to remove default value prior to changing type.
Here is the version with rollback.

```
class ChangeColumnsForSystems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column_default :systems, :status, nil
    change_column :systems, :operation, "integer USING (CASE operation WHEN 'start' THEN '0'::integer ELSE '1'::integer END)", null: false
    change_column :systems, :status, "integer USING (CASE status WHEN 'init' THEN '0'::integer WHEN 'working' THEN '1'::integer ELSE '2'::integer END)", null: false, default: 0
  end

  def down
    change_column_default :systems, :status, nil
    change_column :systems, :operation, "varchar USING (CASE operation WHEN '0' THEN 'start'::varchar ELSE 'stop'::varchar END)", null: false
    change_column :systems, :status, "varchar USING (CASE status WHEN '0' THEN 'init'::varchar WHEN '1' THEN 'working'::varchar ELSE 'complete'::varchar END)", null: false, default: 'init'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in 2 migration steps

1. Rename current `operation` column and add new with neccessary type

```
def up
    rename_column :systems, :operation, :operation_str
    add_column :systems, :operation, ... # your options
end
```

2. Move values from old column to new and drop old column

```
def up
    System.all.each do |sys|
        sys.operation = sys.operation_str.to_i # replace it with your converter
    end
    remove_column :systems, :operation
end
```

Don't forget write rollback code if it's neccessary

Comment: This migration will corrupt all data, because when you call `.to_i` on a string, you will always get 0.

Next piece of code will work as expected. However it's not the best solution
`sys.operation = System.operations[sys.operation_str]`

Comment: Won't this remove the new column you just created rather than dropping the old column?